# PHP Unique Values From Json

Tags: php

I am trying to retrieve a list of unique country codes from my json response. Unfortunately I am not having any luck and I think my code has gone way off track.

My json response looks like:

```
[
{
marketId: "1.131082455",
marketName: "6f Hcap",
marketStartTime: "2017-04-20T12:50:00.000Z",
totalMatched: 4947.48,
runners: [],
eventType: {},
event: {
id: "28198264",
name: "Newm 20th Apr",
countryCode: "GB",
timezone: "Europe/London",
venue: "Newmarket",
openDate: "2017-04-20T12:50:00.000Z"
}
},
{
marketId: "1.131098324",
marketName: "2m4f Listed",
marketStartTime: "2017-04-20T13:05:00.000Z",
totalMatched: 475.02,
runners: [],
eventType: {
id: "7",
name: "Horse Racing"
},
event: {
id: "28199254",
name: "Chelt 20th Apr",
countryCode: "GB",
timezone: "Europe/London",
venue: "Cheltenham",
openDate: "2017-04-20T13:05:00.000Z"
}
},
{
marketId: "1.131098106",
marketName: "5f Nov Stks",
marketStartTime: "2017-04-20T13:15:00.000Z",
totalMatched: 462.02,
runners: [
{
selectionId: 12894664,
runnerName: "Maggies Angel",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 1
},
{
selectionId: 12894662,
runnerName: "Beau Times",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 2
},
{
selectionId: 12894669,
runnerName: "Under Offer",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 3
},
{
selectionId: 12894663,
runnerName: "Che Bella",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 4
},
{
selectionId: 12894666,
runnerName: "Runthatbymeagain",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 5
},
{
selectionId: 12894667,
runnerName: "Societys Dream",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 6
},
{
selectionId: 12894665,
runnerName: "Mount Victoria",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 7
},
{
selectionId: 12894668,
runnerName: "St Helens Gate",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 8
},
{
selectionId: 12894661,
runnerName: "Autumn Belle",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 9
}
],
eventType: {
id: "7",
name: "Horse Racing"
},
event: {
id: "28199240",
name: "Ripon 20th Apr",
countryCode: "GB",
timezone: "Europe/London",
venue: "Ripon",
openDate: "2017-04-20T13:15:00.000Z"
}
},
{
marketId: "1.131082460",
marketName: "7f Hcap",
marketStartTime: "2017-04-20T13:25:00.000Z",
totalMatched: 3215,
runners: [
{
selectionId: 8632310,
runnerName: "Salateen",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 1
},
{
selectionId: 10200126,
runnerName: "Tabarrak",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 2
},
{
selectionId: 2835286,
runnerName: "Accession",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 3
},
{
selectionId: 6793501,
runnerName: "Horsted Keynes",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 4
},
{
selectionId: 10991108,
runnerName: "Castle Harbour",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 5
},
{
selectionId: 9483425,
runnerName: "Qeyaadah",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 6
},
{
selectionId: 10094829,
runnerName: "Mix And Mingle",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 7
}
],
eventType: {
id: "7",
name: "Horse Racing"
},
event: {
id: "28198264",
name: "Newm 20th Apr",
countryCode: "GB",
timezone: "Europe/London",
venue: "Newmarket",
openDate: "2017-04-20T12:50:00.000Z"
}
},
{
marketId: "1.131098329",
marketName: "2m5f Listed",
marketStartTime: "2017-04-20T13:40:00.000Z",
totalMatched: 2092.74,
runners: [
{
selectionId: 8720215,
runnerName: "Antartica De Thaix",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 1
},
{
selectionId: 6879856,
runnerName: "Magic Money",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 2
},
{
selectionId: 9306372,
runnerName: "Plaisir Damour",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 3
},
{
selectionId: 8498571,
runnerName: "Briery Belle",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 4
},
{
selectionId: 10734687,
runnerName: "Bagging Turf",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 5
},
{
selectionId: 8409541,
runnerName: "Storming Strumpet",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 6
},
{
selectionId: 9022305,
runnerName: "Timons Tara",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 7
}
],
eventType: {
id: "7",
name: "Horse Racing"
},
event: {
id: "28199254",
name: "Chelt 20th Apr",
countryCode: "GB",
timezone: "Europe/London",
venue: "Cheltenham",
openDate: "2017-04-20T13:05:00.000Z"
}
},
{
marketId: "1.131098111",
marketName: "5f Nov Stks",
marketStartTime: "2017-04-20T13:50:00.000Z",
totalMatched: 174.22,
runners: [
{
selectionId: 12844624,
runnerName: "Nobrassnolass",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 1
},
{
selectionId: 349630,
runnerName: "Faithful Promise",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 2
},
{
selectionId: 12894672,
runnerName: "Flos Melody",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 3
},
{
selectionId: 12894676,
runnerName: "Showdancing",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 4
},
{
selectionId: 12894674,
runnerName: "Listen Alexander",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 5
},
{
selectionId: 12894670,
runnerName: "Bow Belles",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 6
},
{
selectionId: 12894673,
runnerName: "Kirbec",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 7
},
{
selectionId: 12894675,
runnerName: "Orient Princess",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 8
},
{
selectionId: 12894671,
runnerName: "Capla Dancer",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 9
}
],
eventType: {
id: "7",
name: "Horse Racing"
},
event: {
id: "28199240",
name: "Ripon 20th Apr",
countryCode: "GB",
timezone: "Europe/London",
venue: "Ripon",
openDate: "2017-04-20T13:15:00.000Z"
}
},
{
marketId: "1.131082465",
marketName: "6f Grp 3",
marketStartTime: "2017-04-20T14:00:00.000Z",
totalMatched: 2111.62,
runners: [
{
selectionId: 8556767,
runnerName: "Brando",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 1
},
{
selectionId: 7331634,
runnerName: "Ornate",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 2
},
{
selectionId: 7249496,
runnerName: "Windfast",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 3
},
{
selectionId: 5488936,
runnerName: "Kassia",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 4
},
{
selectionId: 464226,
runnerName: "Aeolus",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 5
},
{
selectionId: 9591578,
runnerName: "Tasleet",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 6
},
{
selectionId: 9507759,
runnerName: "Mayfair Lady",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 7
}
],
eventType: {
id: "7",
name: "Horse Racing"
},
event: {
id: "28198264",
name: "Newm 20th Apr",
countryCode: "GB",
timezone: "Europe/London",
venue: "Newmarket",
openDate: "2017-04-20T12:50:00.000Z"
}
},
{
marketId: "1.131098334",
marketName: "2m4f Listed",
marketStartTime: "2017-04-20T14:15:00.000Z",
totalMatched: 2146.8,
runners: [
{
selectionId: 10839474,
runnerName: "Snow Leopardess",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 1
},
{
selectionId: 6919614,
runnerName: "Indian Stream",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 2
},
{
selectionId: 11208905,
runnerName: "Carnspindle",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 3
},
{
selectionId: 9289732,
runnerName: "Midnight Tour",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 4
},
{
selectionId: 8947698,
runnerName: "Midnight Silver",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 5
},
{
selectionId: 10462183,
runnerName: "Theatre Territory",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 6
},
{
selectionId: 11980162,
runnerName: "Sparkling River",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 7
},
{
selectionId: 8091258,
runnerName: "Tara Mist",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 8
},
{
selectionId: 9483267,
runnerName: "The Organist",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 9
},
{
selectionId: 11154117,
runnerName: "Mariahs Legend",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 10
},
{
selectionId: 9277428,
runnerName: "Miss Tongabezi",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 11
},
{
selectionId: 7728577,
runnerName: "Hopes Wishes",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 12
},
{
selectionId: 7629108,
runnerName: "On Demand",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 13
},
{
selectionId: 9254034,
runnerName: "Miss Crick",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 14
}
],
eventType: {
id: "7",
name: "Horse Racing"
},
event: {
id: "28199254",
name: "Chelt 20th Apr",
countryCode: "GB",
timezone: "Europe/London",
venue: "Cheltenham",
openDate: "2017-04-20T13:05:00.000Z"
}
},
{
marketId: "1.131098116",
marketName: "6f Hcap",
marketStartTime: "2017-04-20T14:25:00.000Z",
totalMatched: 1937.98,
runners: [
{
selectionId: 9527523,
runnerName: "Alkhor",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 1
},
{
selectionId: 8534817,
runnerName: "Dandyleekie",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 2
},
{
selectionId: 8902727,
runnerName: "Magical Effect",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 3
},
{
selectionId: 8522672,
runnerName: "Straightothepoint",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 4
},
{
selectionId: 6482488,
runnerName: "Salvatore Fury",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 5
},
{
selectionId: 9987430,
runnerName: "Rantan",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 6
},
{
selectionId: 8837262,
runnerName: "Gabrial The Tiger",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 7
},
{
selectionId: 8652131,
runnerName: "Eastern Racer",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 8
},
{
selectionId: 7610360,
runnerName: "Royal Connoisseur",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 9
},
{
selectionId: 3186,
runnerName: "Dragon King",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 10
},
{
selectionId: 8722763,
runnerName: "Honeysuckle Lil",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 11
},
{
selectionId: 4299084,
runnerName: "Best Trip",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 12
},
{
selectionId: 10304529,
runnerName: "Mywayistheonlyway",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 13
},
{
selectionId: 9504726,
runnerName: "Still On Top",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 14
},
{
selectionId: 10174031,
runnerName: "Taskeen",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 15
}
],
eventType: {
id: "7",
name: "Horse Racing"
},
event: {
id: "28199240",
name: "Ripon 20th Apr",
countryCode: "GB",
timezone: "Europe/London",
venue: "Ripon",
openDate: "2017-04-20T13:15:00.000Z"
}
},
{
marketId: "1.131082470",
marketName: "1m Grp 3",
marketStartTime: "2017-04-20T14:35:00.000Z",
totalMatched: 10616.28,
runners: [
{
selectionId: 11252663,
runnerName: "War Decree",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 1
},
{
selectionId: 11472950,
runnerName: "Rivet",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 2
},
{
selectionId: 11378900,
runnerName: "Larchmont Lad",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 3
},
{
selectionId: 12685204,
runnerName: "Benbatl",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 4
},
{
selectionId: 11576840,
runnerName: "Eminent",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 5
},
{
selectionId: 5443284,
runnerName: "Gulliver",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 6
},
{
selectionId: 11478374,
runnerName: "Contrapposto",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 7
}
],
eventType: {
id: "7",
name: "Horse Racing"
},
event: {
id: "28198264",
name: "Newm 20th Apr",
countryCode: "IE",
timezone: "Europe/London",
venue: "Newmarket",
openDate: "2017-04-20T12:50:00.000Z"
}
}
]
```

and what I am trying to do is now display the unique 'countryCode' values (which I know are 'GB' and 'IE'. Unfortunately for me, my code is not doing much.

Here is what I have (sorry it's gone kind of sloppy now):

```
<?php

$api_url = "http://localhost:8888/api/"; 


$jsondata = file_get_contents($api_url); 
$obj = json_decode($jsondata, true);





if (is_array($obj)){

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>
            <th>Meeting</th>

         </tr>";
    foreach ($obj as $row){

        $meeting = $row["marketNam"];
        $race_id = $row["marketId"];
        $venue = $row["event"]["venue"];
        $date = $row["event"]["openDate"];
        $countryCode = $row["event"]["countryCode"];

        $dateFormatted = date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $date);


        $values = array_unique($countryCode, SORT_REGULAR);


        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><a href='#'>".$values."</a></td>";
            //echo "<td><a href='races.php?id=".$race_id."&venue=".$meeting."'>".$venue."</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

?>
```

Comment: In your code, `$countryCode` will be a single value, not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `$countryCode` will be a single value, not an array. I'm not sure exactly what you are doing with the table, but here are a couple of ways to get a unique list of country codes:

```
// iterate your data and add each item's country to a $countries array
foreach ($obj as $row) {
    $countries[] = $row['event']['countryCode'];
}
// use array_unique to remove duplicates
$countries = array_unique($countries);
```

or

```
// iterate your data and add each item's country to a $countries array
foreach ($obj as $row) {
    // using countryCode as the key will keep the array unique.
    $countries[$row['event']['countryCode']] = true;
}
//swap the keys to values
$countries = array_keys($countries);
```

Using one of these approaches would mean you'd have to get the unique list before outputting anything, then iterate the resulting list to output.